# Oracle INACTIVE session with INSERT command and WAITING state

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-xe

I have a java code that connect to Oracle XE server and insert some data. for some reason the application is stuck when trying to connect to the server after several  calls (it an integration test which uses the database so there are many connect and close calls).
when running the following query :

```
select s.status, s.state,sid, command, osuser,machine,port,serial#,
  listagg(st.sql_text,'') within group (order by st.sql_id, st.piece)
from v$session s inner join v$sqltext_with_newlines st
  on s.sql_id = st.sql_id and s.sql_hash_value = st.hash_value
where username = 'MY_USERNAME'
group by s.status, s.state,sid, command, osuser,machine,port,serial#;
```

I get this  :

```
STATUS   STATE    SID  COMMAND  OSUSER  MACHINE   PORT  SERIAL#  SQL_TEXT
-------- -------- ---- -------- ------- --------- ----- -------- -----------------------------------------
INACTIVE WAITING  104  2        jenkins simba-vm  42017 33187    insert into table (.....) values (.....);
```

I killed the session, cleared the cache, dropped and created the table again, shutdown and started the server again but it always stuck in this query.

Comment: It can be possible in one condition which i can think off. If your java code connects with one DB user and another DB user is doing the INSERT. So for that moment the first connection will be in WAITING state unless the transaction from second DB user is completed.

Comment: Find the session which is blocking your 104 session. They are concurrent for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've check the object that lock the session and its ORA$BASE but I cant understand why, there are no other sessions that calls the table.

Comment: Look at the EVENT column a few times, it will tell you what the query is waiting on.